# Can not run metricbeat in docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I am trying to run metricbeat using docker in windows machine and I have changed metricbeat.yml as per my requirement.

```
docker run -v /c/Users/someuser/docker/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:5.6.0
```

but getting these error

> metricbeat2017/09/17 10:13:19.285547 beat.go:346: CRIT Exiting: error
>   loading config file: config file ("metricbeat.yml") can only be
>   writable by the owner but the permissions are "-rwxrwxrwx" (to fix the
>   permissions use: 'chmod go-w /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml')
>       Exiting: error loading config file: config file ("metricbeat.yml") can only be writable by the owner but the permissions are "-rwxrwxrwx"
>   (to fix the permissions use: 'chmod go-w /
>       usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml')

Why I am getting this?

**What is the right way to make permanent change in file content in docker container (As I don't want to change configuration file each time when container start)**

Edit:
Container is not meant to be edited / changed.If necessary, docker volume management is available to externalize all configuration related works.Thanks

Comment: Try running this `docker run -v /c/Users/someuser/docker/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:5.6.0 chmod go-w / usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml` and then your command and see if it helps. If it doesn't help then it may be because of the fact that originally the files or on windows and windows doesn't have such permissions. So even if you make the change it will not be persisted

Comment: command is not working. Fortunately , I have managed to start the metricbeat container by creating a new file within virtual machine and command was docker run -v /home/docker/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbea‌​t/metricbeat.yml --name metricbeat docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:5.6.0 instead of accessing windows location. There must be a better approach to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are 2 options you can do here I think.

The first is that you can ensure the file has the proper permissions:

```
chmod 644 metricbeat.yml
```

Or you can run your docker command with `-strict.perms=false` which flags that metricbeat shouldn't care about what permissions are on the `metricbeat.yml` file.

```
docker run \
  docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:5.6.0 \
  --volume="/c/Users/someuser/docker/metricbeat.yml:/usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml" \
  -strict.perms=false
```

You can see more documentation about that flag in the link below:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/command-line-options.html#global-flags

Comment: For Dockerfile with config copy add the following line after copy: RUN chmod 644 /usr/share/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml